# Include a javascript file in Shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I need to include a js library into my Shiny app. Currently I use includeHTML to include the script directly into html codes. e.g.

```
includeHTML('URL.js')
```

The browser will show "Not Found" when I try to browser the js file if I use tags$script, e.g.

```
http://127.0.0.1:7106/URL.js

tags$script(src = 'URL.js')
```

Now I put URL.js in the same folder of ui.r and server.r.

Where I should store the URL.js file? Or are there other ways to include a js file?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. create `www` folder in the same folder as `server.R` and `ui.R`
2. put javascript file into `www` folder.
3. put `tags$head(tags$script(src="hoge.js"))` in UI.

The folder looks like:

```
├── server.R
├── ui.R
└── www
    └── hoge.js
```

The `ui.R` is something like

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("New Application"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", 
                "Number of observations:", 
                min = 1, 
                max = 1000, 
                value = 500)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot"),
    tags$head(tags$script(src="hoge.js"))
  )
))
```

and `server.R`

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
    hist(dist)
  })
})
```

Note that these are templates generated by Rstudio.

Now `head` of html looks like:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  ... snip ...
  <script src="shared/slider/js/jquery.slider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="hoge.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Or use `includeScript` which takes an argument `path` the base path being the Shiny application directory. `includeScript` however will place the javascript  from the file inline.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to ad React to a Shiny application?

Comment: it is possible to add script in first position of all the script before all the package script ? 
For example i wanted to make a leaflet map with many layers so i need to add `<script>L_PREFER_CANVAS = true;</script>` before adding the `<script src="leaflet.js"></script>` but the solution you provide add the script at the end

Answer (score 13):

Another way is to use:

```
includeScript("mapManipulator.js"),
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 └──shiny
    ├── server.R
    ├── ui.R
    └── www
        ├── stylesheet.css
        └── js
             └── hoge.js
```

## ui.R

Either one of them will work

```
1. tags$head(HTML("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/hoge.js'></script>"))

2. HTML('<head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoge.js"></script>
          </head>')
```

Answer (score 3):

My preferred way is like this:

ui.R:

```
    extendShinyjs(script = "app.js", functions = c("alerta")),
```

app.js:

```
shinyjs.alerta = function(text){
  alert(text);
}
```

server.R

```
  js$alerta("alerta alerta antifascista")
```

You can also include code like this:

ui.R after library imports:

```
jsCode <- "shinyjs.alerta = function(text){alert(text);}"
```

ui.R inside fluidPage:

```
extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("alerta")),
```

the call from server.R would be the same

Answer (score 2):

Another option not discussed yet is that you just delete the ui.R file entirely, and then code the entire thing as a custom HTML file. Details here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html

In this article, the default HTML form elements are automatically used as inputs in server.R, but you can also build custom input (or output) elements for shiny with this guide https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html