# How to fix the columns of dataTables when scrolling in shiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I want to freeze the header and(or) the first column of the table as what we can do easily in Excel when using renderDataTable in shiny.
I guess we can plug in the extensions of dataTable in the link below:
http://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

But I don't know much about java, can anybody provide an example about implementing the extensions in shiny?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can file a feature request to https://github.com/rstudio/DT

Answer (score 1):

Mayb using `googleVis` package can be of help

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("googleVis on Shiny"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a data:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("table")
          )
  ),
  server =function(input, output)({
    output$table <- renderGvis({
      ## Table with enabled paging
      tbl2 <- gvisTable(Population, options=list(page='enable', height=300, alternatingRowStyle = T), chartid = "mytable")
      tbl2
    })    
  })
  )
)
```

Comment: Is there any possible to use the datatables extensions in http://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/ directly? It looks quite fancy.

Comment: may br you can a `javascript ` provided to the app check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599268/include-a-javascript-file-in-shiny-app

Comment: Thank you Keniajin, I will follow the instructions in the link and try to implement the java script in Shiny. Thanks.