# Include javascript file in a single-file Shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I need to include a js file in a single-file shiny app. I tried to work with a two file app (classic UI-Server) and it works, but when I try to add the Javascript file into a single-file app, using the same structure, the browser can't find the js file.

This is the structure that I use into a two-file application, and works properly:

```
├── server.R
├── ui.R
└── www
   └── main.js
```

And this is the tag that I use to add the js file in the ui.R code:

```
tags$head(tags$script(src="main.js"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include a javascript file in Shiny app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599268/include-a-javascript-file-in-shiny-app)

Comment: As I said, I already added a js file in a Shiny app using Server.R and UI.R. What I ask is to add a js file in a single-file Shiny app.

Comment: Well then you need to declare it just before the `shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {  }`

Comment: Just put the `main.js` in www folder and call `tags$head(tags$script(src="main.js"))` in the `ui` function

Answer (score 0):

To add to the solution:

If you want to include a js file from server, use:

```
ui = fluidPage(

useShinyjs(),
tags$head(tags$script(src="https://tab.worldbank.org/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js")))
```

If you want also want to include customized local js functions, add additional    line with **your path + js file name**, e.g.:

```
extendShinyjs(script = "C:/Users/Desktop/YourFile.js")
```

Note here: in each js function inside extendShinyjs, it should be **prefixed using shinyjs**. e.g.:

```
shinyjs.switchView = function(sheetname) {
 var workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
 workbook.activateSheetAsync(sheetname);
 }
```