# R Shiny - Trigger a shinyalert popup directly from the UI using javascript

Tags: r, shiny, shinyalert

With the following piece of code I'm able to trigger a pure javascript `alert` by clicking on the question-mark of the fileInput:

[image]

```
            fileInput('peptides', 
                      span("Peptides file  ",
                           id="peptidesSpan",
                           tags$a(
                             tags$i(class='fa fa-question-circle'),
                             href = "#",
                             onclick = "alert('Oops!'); return false;")
                      ),
                      multiple=FALSE,
                      accept = c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values',
                      )
            )
```

I was wondering if I could trigger a `shinyalert` popup (https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert/) instead of a simple javascript alert directly form the UI without any observer in the server side.

Something like:

```
shinyalert("Oops!", "Something went wrong.", type = "error")
```

If there is not a workaround to do that, any other suggestion with an observer would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using an observer is not at all inconvenient.

Instead of `alert()`, invoke `Shiny.setInputValue(id, value);`, and then on your server side you can `observeEvent(input[id], { shinyalert() })`.

Read this article for details: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html

You only need to use one observe code block to achieve this.

An example

Define a customized function in your UI Javascript code and call it in your `onclick`.
You can put this function say in helper.js in the 'www' folder in your project folder, that will be `www/helper.js`. Include this file in your Shiny UI code by `tags$head(tags$script(src = "helper.js"))`

```
function showAlert(message, type = "info") {
  Shiny.setInputValue(
    'alertMessage',
    {
      message: message,
      type: type
    },
    { priority: 'event' }
  );
}
```

Then on the Shiny server side define the observer once

```
observeEvent(input$alertMessage, {
  alertData <- input$alertMessage
  req(alertData)

  shinyalert("title", alertData$message, type = alertData$type)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the few times that I answer my own post, but after searching a bit more on stack-overflow I found a workaround inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599268/include-a-javascript-file-in-shiny-app) post.

1. I downloaded the `sweetAlert.js` file of the Sweet Alert library directly from [here](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2)
2. I create a `www` folder in the root of my Shiny application
3. I added the sweetAlert.js file in the `www` directory and in the dashboardBody() of the ui.R I added the following line:

   `tags$head(tags$script(src="sweetAlert.js"))`

Now I'm able to call directly the `Swal.fire` function with any argument as I would normally do in any other framework which runs javascript.

Comment: I just realised that if I incorporate the sweetAlert.js file as I described above, the shinyalert() function in server.R stops being functional (perhaps because the sweetAlert.js overrides the `useShinyalert()`)