# Make additional kable header row from add_header_above() sticky

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

As outlined in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514513/r-shiny-make-additional-header-row-of-kable-table-sticky), the `kableExtra` package has a function `add_header_above()` which creates an additional header row in the output table on top of the actual column names. However, when setting `fixed_thead = TRUE` in `kable_styling()` to make the header sticky, the additional header row from the `add_header_above()` call is not made sticky.

Minimal example to demonstrate the problem:

```
knitr::kable(mtcars) %>%
    kableExtra::add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Header 1" = 5, "Header 2" = 6)) %>%
    kableExtra::kable_styling(fixed_thead = TRUE)
```

In the above linked [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514513/r-shiny-make-additional-header-row-of-kable-table-sticky) there is a solution given using shiny apps, but **could someone please provide a solution for making the `add_header_above()` headers sticky without using a shiny app?** I'm looking for a solution that does not require knitting in r markdown, as I would like to be able to just save the table using `save_kable()` instead of having to knit the whole script